# "needs to be update" on xcode IOS simulato/ Failed to find matching arch for input file:

Tags: java, xcode, ios-simulator

I add my app to ios (16.2) Iphone 14 pro simulator, and simulator returned this error:

```
Failed to find matching arch for input file: /Users/aliyevey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76BDC6B2-A011-4202-BA6F-E400D1296546/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.lpSELw/extracted/customer_bank.app/customer_bank
Xcode 14.3.1 Simulator - Iphone 14 pro. IOS 16.4 My application 'Customer_pank' is currently in the testing environment. I intend to integrate this application into the simulator for testing purposes. However, upon attempting to add the application to the simulator, an error message is returned, which reads as follows: "Failed to find matching arch for input file: /Users/aliyevey/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/76BDC6B2-A011-4202-BA6F-E400D1296546/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.lpSELw/extracted/customer_bank.app/customer_bank"

aliyevey@KapMac426-M ~ % uname -a Darwin KapMac426-M.local 22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul 5 22:21:56 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 aliyevey@KapMac426-M ~ % lipo -info /Users/aliyevey/Downloads/customer_bank.app/customer_bank Non-fat file: /Users/aliyevey/Downloads/customer_bank.app/customer_bank is architecture: arm64
```

Due to architectural differences between the Macbook and the application, there is an issue causing the application to not function properly on the simulator. How can I resolve this?"

[image]

```
aliyevey@KapMac426-M ~ % uname -a Darwin KapMac426-M.local 22.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.6.0: Wed Jul 5 22:21:56 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.141.3~6/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 aliyevey@KapMac426-M ~ % lipo -info /Users/aliyevey/Downloads/customer_bank.app/customer_bank Non-fat file: /Users/aliyevey/Downloads/customer_bank.app/customer_bank is architecture: arm64
```

Due to architectural differences between the Macbook and the application, there is an issue causing the application to not function properly on the simulator.